# Is there a way to drain parts of a vector based on a predicate?

Tags: vector, rust, predicate

I'm trying to remove some elements from a vector, based on a predicate, and collecting the result. Here's a (not working) example with an expected result:

```
let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

let drained: Vec<i32> = v.iter().filter(|e| (*e) % 2 == 0).drain(..).collect();

assert_eq!(v, vec![1, 3, 5]);
assert_eq!(drained, vec![2, 4, 6]);
```

This results in the error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `drain` found for type `std::iter::Filter<std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>, [closure@src/main.rs:4:45: 4:62]>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:4:64
  |
4 |     let drained: Vec<i32> = v.iter().filter(|e| (*e) % 2 == 0).drain(..).collect();
  |                                                                ^^^^^
```

There are several alternatives I looked at, none of them seem to be doing what I want:

- `Vec::retain` removes the elements from the vector, but doesn't give back ownership of the removed elements.
- `v.drain(..).filter(condition).collect()` returns the correct value for `drained` but empties the whole vector.

Comment: have you tried converting the array with to_vec? 
`let drained: Vec<i32> = v.iter().filter(|e| (*e) % 2 == 0).to_vec().drain(..).collect();`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not in stable Rust 1.33.0. There's an unstable nightly feature called `drain_filter` that does exactly what you want:

```
#![feature(drain_filter)]

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    let drained: Vec<i32> = v.drain_filter(|&mut e| e % 2 == 0).collect();

    assert_eq!(v, vec![1, 3, 5]);
    assert_eq!(drained, vec![2, 4, 6]);
}
```

As a stable workaround, you may be able to use `Iterator::partition`, but it does not reuse the memory:

```
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    let (drained, v): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = v.into_iter().partition(|&e| e % 2 == 0);

    assert_eq!(v, vec![1, 3, 5]);
    assert_eq!(drained, vec![2, 4, 6]);
}
```

Comment: For future reference: the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2140), and the [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43244)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest few other ways to do this + my benchmarks.

**N.B.** I compare all methods by few criteria:

1. Does it support external source of truth (my use-case). E.g. `Vec::retain` supports that, meaning that you can write code like

```rust
// conditions: &[bool]
assert_eq!(conditions.len(), my_vec.len());
let cond = conditions.iter().copied();
my_vec.retain(move|_|cond.next().unwrap());
```

2. Is method supported by third-party `Vec`s, namely ArrayVec, TinyVec, SmallVec, FixedSliceVec and others.
3. Is it fast.

So, let's begin

#### Sort slice than split slice

Features:

1. Can support external source of truth — No ❌. Would call closure *O(n log n)* times in unspecified order so support only predicates which calculated only directly from values.
2. Third-party support — Excellent ✅. You can use it on anything convertible to mutable slice.
3. Is it fast — In generic case, no ❌. It runs for *O(n log n)* time while other methods run for *O(n)* time. However, if preserving original relative order is not important for you, you can use `sort_unstable_by_key` which doesn't allocate memory at all, which can make it fastest in some scenarios.

Implementation:

```rust
v.sort_by_key(|x| predicate(x));
let split_pos = v.partition_point(|x| predicate(x));
let (false_slice, true_slice) = v.split_at_mut(split_pos)
```

#### `Vec::drain_filter`

1. Can support external source of truth — Yes ✅. Visits items in original order exactly one time.
2. Third-party support — Non existent ❌. Also, you can't it even use in stable Rust and [it's tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43244) has been suffering from bikeshedding 5 years now (at 2022-07).
3. Is it fast — Yes ✅.

Code

```rust
let removed_items: Vec<_> = v.drain_filter(|x| predicate(x)).collect();
```

#### `MaybeUninit` trick using `unsafe` code

Well, I wrote it myself.

Features:

1. Can support external source of truth — Yes ✅. Visits items in original order exactly one time.
2. Third-party support — Supported ✅. Note that you **must** audit their implementation of `retain` to ensure that it cannot panic itself.
3. Is it fast — Yes ✅. In my benchmarks it is faster than `Vec::drain_filter`.

This implementation makes 2 assumptions:

1. Internal layout of `Vec<T>` and `Vec<MaybeUninit<T>>` is same. There is no reason why it is not because memory layout of `T` and `MaybeUninit<T>` is same but I also verify this using asserts. Note that asserts would be removed by compiler optimizer because they are always true.
2. `retain` doesn't panic itself (it can only propagate panics from element drop or from predicate). This is true for `std::vec::Vec` but you need to ensure that for third-party crates.

Algorithm is simple:

1. reinterpret initial vector `Vec<T>` as `Vec<MaybeUninit<T>>`;
2. wrap our predicate into new predicate that moves items which we want to remove into external storage;
3. let `Vec::retain` handle removal of items.

Also, only reason of usage of `MaybeUninit` and unsafe is avoiding double-frees so if your elements implement `Copy`, this algorithm can be implemented in safe Rust.
However, in that case you can just use `filter(...).collect()` and `retain` with almost same performance.

So, code is below with all comments why it is safe (note that I didn't test it using sanitizers or Miri so use it on your own risk):

```rust
/// Returns removed values.
fn retain_unsafe_generic<T: Sized>(
    v: &mut Vec<T>,
    mut which_to_keep: impl FnMut(&T) -> bool,
) -> Vec<T> {
    use std::mem::{transmute, MaybeUninit};

    /// # Safety
    /// Caller must ensure that if it makes living copies of inner items,
    /// those items is removed from original vec before original reference became usable again.
    unsafe fn as_uninits<T: Sized>(v: &mut Vec<T>) -> &mut Vec<MaybeUninit<T>> {
        let orig_ptr = v.as_ptr();
        let orig_cap = v.capacity();
        let orig_size = v.len();

        let v: &mut Vec<MaybeUninit<T>> = unsafe {
            // Safety: since `MaybeUninit` has same memory layout
            // as wrapped type, we assume that we can treat vec with T
            // as MaybeUninit<T>. This assumption checked by asserts below.
            //
            // Lifetimes of elements must be correctly enforced by caller.
            transmute(v)
        };
        // Check if layout of Vec with different element type remains same.
        assert_eq!(v.len(), orig_size);
        assert_eq!(v.capacity(), orig_cap);
        assert_eq!(v.as_ptr(), orig_ptr.cast());

        v
    }

    let mut res: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(v.len());
    let v = unsafe {
        // Safety: we keep result reference only in `retain` call.
        // We would remove all moved elements using retain.
        as_uninits(v)
    };
    v.retain(
        // Safety: `Vec::retain` would remove all items which values we moved into `res`.
        // It wouldn call `drop::<T>` for removed values
        // because `MaybeUninit` never drops wrapped values.
        |x| unsafe {
            // Safety: it is safe because `Vec::retain` visits elements sequentally
            // so we haven't moved value from `x` yet.
            // https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain
            let val = &*x.as_ptr();
            if which_to_keep(val) {
                return true;
            }
            res.reserve(1);
            // Any panic before this place is safe because
            // 1. We didn't moved value from `x` yet;
            // 2. In case of panic in predicate, `Vec::retain` preserve current value.

            // Here we could probably use `Vec::push`
            // but compiler currently fails to remove capacity check in `Vec::push`
            // so this function became slower than `Vec::drain_filter`
            // https://godbolt.org/z/7fhnnMh46
            // And `Vec::push(x.assume_init_read())` is unsafe operation too anyway.

            let old_len = res.len();
            // Safety: We just allocated memory for this place.
            let dst = res.as_mut_ptr().add(old_len);
            // Safety: since we cannot panic until the end of closure
            // and `Vec::retain` wouldn't panic and would remove `x`,
            // making bitwise copy of `x` is safe.
            x.as_ptr().copy_to_nonoverlapping(dst, 1);
            // Safety: we just wrote additional value.
            res.set_len(old_len + 1);

            false
        },
    );

    res
}
```

## Benchmarks

Code of benchmarks is long so here link to the gist: https://gist.github.com/AngelicosPhosphoros/7ee482316bc1c83945f88308954e0d7e
It tries to split away odd numbers from they `Vec` using all three algorithms I listed.

Results:

| algorithm | Mixed | Odds first | Evens first |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sort-split | 465us | 35us | 10us |
| drain_filter | 26us | 24us | 22.5us |
| retain-uninit | 17us | 21us | 19us |

As you see, retain usage won in all cases except when sort-split doesn't actually have anything to do.
It is mainly because `Vec::retain` has been rigorously optimized over the years.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation state that Vec.retain will operate in-place, and visit each element in order, exactly once.

```
fn drain_where<T, Pred : Fn(&T) -> bool>(source: &mut Vec<T>, pred: Pred) -> Vec<T>
  where T : Copy {
  let mut drained: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
  
  source.retain(|item| {
    if pred(item) { drained.push(*item); false } else { true }
  });
  
  drained
}
```

Comment: It only works with types that are `Copy`, so not generally useful